# Migrating from OneSignal to Firebase push notifications

Tags: firebase, onesignal

I have a large number of users subscribed to OneSignal. Is there a way to export all this data to firebase so I don't have to wait for the users to subscribe again.

One Signal provides a similar functionality to import Users data from Parse and you could send push notifications to them.
https://onesignal.com/parse

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. Possibly I'll have to find how OneSignal internally creates Player Id and how it works with FCM/GCM or Apple push notification service.

Comment: You can export all the users via CSV which contains the fcmToken which you need to send a notification. However at the moment I cannot get the permissions to work in order to send to those devices.

Comment: @Dan did you manage to make permissions to work ?

Comment: @HugoPozzoli This was awhile ago but I believe the OneSignal support team ended up providing me with the proper CSV export that had all the information I needed to get it working.